# Using biblatex-apa

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I got biblatex working with the authoryear style in Texlipse:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[canadian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document} 
This statement is true \parencite[5-8]{Ref}.
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

references.bib:

```
@BOOK
{Ref,
AUTHOR = "Doe, Jane and Smith, John",
TITLE = "A Book",
PUBLISHER = "Books, Inc.",
YEAR = 1999
}
```

However, when I try to change the style to apa (`\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}`), an empty bibliography is produced. I have texlive 2012, which has biblatex-apa. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your example compiles fine.

Comment: Are you sure that TeXlipse is set for using Biber rather than BibTeX?

Comment: I think that [biber is set](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/biblatex.html). I've read that pdflatex has to be run twice to work correctly; however, so far I've been hitting ctrl-s to save and "build". How am I to pdflatex twice in TeXlipse?

Comment: Hmmm... Strange. What operating system are you using? I tried this again on an Ubuntu 12.04 platform in the office and I can verify that the bibliography disappears when the style was changed from `authoryear` to `apa`. But I can't be of further help. I don't use TeXlipse myself. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried to rerun `biber` after you changed from `authoryear` to `apa`? Not sure about TeXlipse, but you can remove the `.bbl` file to force rebuild (run again `biber`).

Comment: That solves the problem. It's seems there should be a better way to do it in TeXlipse, but removing the `.bbl` forces TeXlipse to rerun  biber. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

On Miktex your example with apa doesn't work due to two reasons:

1. There is the language mapping commands missing which loads an `xxx-apa.lbx` which contains some apa specific settings.
2. You are using `canadian` as language and the necessary `canadian-apa.lbx` doesn't exist here.

To solve 1. I used the following example (`test.bib` is the name of my bib-files for tests):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[canadian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{canadian}{canadian-apa}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
This statement is true \parencite[5-8]{Ref}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

To solve 2. I used one existing `xxx-apa.lbx` (e.g. `british-apa.lbx` or `american-apa.lbx` I have no idea which is better suited as starting point) and made a copy called `canadian-apa.lbx`. Then I changed in the file in two places the language to "canadian":

1. In the first line: `\ProvidesFile{canadian-apa.lbx}`
2. In `\DefineBibliographyExtras{canadian}...`

and stored the file in a place where latex can find it.

An alternative way is to use e.g. the language `american` for the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[canadian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,language=american]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
This statement is true \parencite[5-8]{Ref}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that Miktex is more picky than TeXLive. Perhaps these are still good habits to pick up?

Comment: @user21760 I get the same error (undefined `\mkbibdateapalongextra` when the language is not set up correctly) with texlive 2012. And if the systems were really different it would be due to different `biblatex-apa` versions.