# How to modify a bibliography style to surround titles in quotes in a bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, punctuation

My advisor wants me to cause all titles for papers, books, and articles in `"` for my thesis in my bibliography.

I am using `natbib` and the `plainnat` bibliography style and am unsure how to do this. I am NOT asking how to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901180/how-to-preserve-quotes-in-bibtex) or displaying a quote in the title, I want to make the title show `"` around it with capitalization being saved. I could go through and manually modify the .bib file I suppose...

Here is a working example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}                 
@Article{Hart,
author = {P.E. Hart, N.J. Nilsson, B. Raphael},
title = {Correction to a Formal Basis for the Heuristic Determination of Minimum Cost Paths },
journal = {SIGART Newsletter 37},
year = {1972},
pages = {28-29}
}       
@Article{Hart2,
author = {P.E. Hart, N.J. Nilsson, B. Raphael},
title = { {``Correction to a Formal Basis for the Heuristic Determination of Minimum Cost Paths''}  },
journal = {SIGART Newsletter 37},
year = {1972},
pages = {28-29}
}
\end{filecontents}  

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

    I don't want it to look like this reference \cite{Hart}

    I want it to look like this \cite{Hart2}

\bibliography{mybib}


\end{document}
```

Is there a way to easily do this? I can always hack this by doing what I did for the second reference if not.

From reading [this documentation](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/natnotes2.pdf) nothing stands out to me as doing this?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't change your `.bib` file. It might be easiest to use `makebst` to create a new `.bst` file. From the command line, type `latex makebst` and follow the directions. There is an option for putting article titles in quotation marks. (You'll also probably want to put conference proceedings and technical reports in quotation marks as well.)

Comment: I just read your request more carefully. Does your advisor *really* want book titles to be in quotes?  This is really unorthodox in most bibliography styles I know of (maybe it's standard in your field, however.)  If so, my answer will need some modification.  Book and journal titles are typically set in italics.

Comment: @AlanMunn `Put the title of the paper, book or article within double quotes.`  I don't question things at the point where I'm just making revisions :)

Comment: Ok, then I recommend you use my second method.  I'll update my answer with a stern warning. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't modify your `.bib` file by adding the quotation marks there. This will cause you no end of trouble in the future.  Here are two solutions.

### Use `makebst`

It's possible to the use `makebst` program to generate a new `.bst` file for yourself.  To do this, you can open a command line window and type:

```
latex makebst
```

This will walk you through a whole bunch of menus of choices, including the following:

```
<many choices before>

<<TITLE OF ARTICLE:
(*) Title plain with no special font
(i) Title italic (\em)
(q) Title and punctuation in single quotes (`Title,' ..)
(d) Title and punctuation in double quotes (``Title,'' ..)
(g) Title and punctuation in guillemets (<<Title,>> ..)
(x) Title in single quotes (`Title', ..)
(y) Title in double quotes (``Title'', ..)
(z) Title in guillemets (<<Title>>, ..)
  Select:

\ans=d
  You have selected: Title and punctuation in double quotes

>>TITLE OF ARTICLE:

<<COLLECTION/PROCEEDINGS TITLES (if quoted title)
(*) Quote collection and proceedings titles too
(x) Collection and proceedings titles not in quotes 
  Select:

\ans=
  You have selected: Quote collection and proceedings titles

<many choices after>
```

Then you just use this new `.bst` file for your thesis.  You can put it in the same folder as the main `.tex` file of your thesis, or put it in your local `texmf` folder (on a TeXLive system is should go in `<path-to-local-texmf>/texmf/bib/bst`.

### Make a new `.bst` file which uses `csquotes` for quoting

Instead of doing things this way, if you are comfortable with editing your own copy of `plainnat.bst` here's a method which uses the `csquotes` package to do the quotation. This handles punctuation correctly and also allows you to easily change from single to double quotes if you need.  It does involve some work, though, but probably will take less time than stepping through all the `makebst` choices (especially if you don't know what each one is asking.)

First, make a copy of `plainnat.bst` in the same folder of your `.tex` file and rename it (e.g. `plainnat-csquotes.bst`).

Now make the following changes/additions to that file:

First, we add a function `format.atitle` similar to the `format.btitle` function on line 432 of `plainnat.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {format.atitle}
{ title enquote
}
```

Next, we add an `enquote` function similar to the `emphasize` function on line 207 of `plainnat.bst`. Note that this uses the `\textquote` macro from the `csquotes` package, so this `.bst` file will require that package to be loaded. We are using the `\textquote` macro instead of the more general `\enquote` macro so that we can redefine it to place the punctuation correctly according to American standards (punctuation is always inside the quotation mark.)

```
FUNCTION {enquote}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    {pop$ "" }
    {"\textquote{" swap$ * "}" * }
    if$
}
```

Finally we need to change any entry type that needs quotation marks around its title to use the `format.atitle` function instead of the `format.title` function.  In my opinion, this should include (for consistency) the `article`, `incollection`, `inproceedings`, `techreport`, and `unpublished` entry types.  If you search through the `.bst` file you will find a function for each of them.  Here's the `article` function as an example: (before the change:)

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      eid empty$
        { format.vol.num.pages output }
        { format.vol.num.eid output }
      if$
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      eid empty$
        { format.pages output }
        { format.eid output }
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.issn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

We now change the line

```
format.title "title" output.check
```

to:

```
format.atitle "title" output.check
```

Do this for each of the other entry types listed above.

You now have a `csquotes` aware `.bst` file.  To use it, you simply need to add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-csquotes}
```

To implement correct placement of the punctuation with respect to the quotation mark we need to add the following extra line:

```
\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#5#3#6}
```

This will place the punctuation inside the quotation marks.

#### Changing the format of book titles too

Your advisor has requested that book titles also use quotation marks.  This is a very unorthodox style, and I don't recommend it at all, but if that's what he wants, it's easy enough to do.  Simply find the `format.btitle` function and change it from:

```
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
    { title emphasize
    }
```

to

```
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
    { title enquote
    }
```

Comment: Very nice tutorial. +1

Comment: This is awesome, opened my eyes to a whole new world of LaTeX :)  You know of a good way to stop the `end of title".` from being like that but rather `end of title."` ?

Comment: @enderland Thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the answer.  (Slight change to the `.bst` function and one extra line of code in the preamble.)

Answer (score 3):

It's more straightforward with biblatex.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,
   unpublished,techreport,misc,book]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
```

-- for example.

If you were going this route, presumably you would invoke biblatex with options like this, so that you can keep on using your natbib citation commands:

```
\usepackage[style=apa,
            natbib,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

(Note that standard caveats about [Using biblatex-apa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80440/using-biblatex-apa) apply.)

---

Here's a MWE that introduces another [trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326997/4357) to preserve casing.  Removing the period delimiter is more complicated and I'm not sure it's really required/desired.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english, american]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,
            natbib,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,
   unpublished,techreport,misc,book]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{sloterdijk2013change,
  title={You Must Change Your Life},
  author={Sloterdijk, P.},
  publisher={Polity Press},
  year={2013}
}
@Article{Hart,
author = {P.E. Hart, N.J. Nilsson, B. Raphael},
title = {Correction to a Formal Basis for the Heuristic Determination of Minimum Cost Paths },
journal = {SIGART Newsletter 37},
year = {1972},
pages = {28-29}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\noindent \cite{Hart}.

\noindent Cf. Sloterdijk \citeyear[(pp. 84--85)]{sloterdijk2013change}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\mkbibquote{#1}` instead of ```#1''`. It is also a good idea to load the `csquotes` package then. Note that the default is `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}` which is pretty much what you have there.

Comment: I updated w/ `\mkbibquote` and an MWE.  Getting rid of the dot looks tricky!