# apalike bibliographystyle:: how to quote title of each article?

Tags: natbib, punctuation, apa-style

I am using apalike biblographystile in latex. I would like to quote each article title. 
Currently, my latex file looks like:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{apalike}
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \begin{document}
  Here is my text followed by citation in bracket \citep{myCitation}.
 \bibliographystyle{apalike} 
 \bibliography{myRef.bib}
 \end{document}
```

Then my reference looks like:

> Zhao, Y., Petkau, A. J., Traboulsee, A., Riddehough, A., and Li, D. K. B. (2010). Does
>   MRI lesion activity regress in secondary progressive multiple sclerosis? *Multiple
>   Sclerosis*, 16:434-442.

However, I want the article title to be:

> Zhao, Y., Petkau, A. J., Traboulsee, A., Riddehough, A., and Li, D. K. B. (2010). "Does
>   MRI lesion activity regress in secondary progressive multiple sclerosis?" *Multiple
>   Sclerosis*, 16:434-442.

Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: This probably answers the question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120722/how-to-modify-natbib-to-surround-titles-in-quotes-in-a-bibliography

Comment: Should quotation marks be placed around only the titles of entries of type `@journal`, or around those of types such as `@techreport`, `@misc`, and `@unpublished` as well?