# How to modify a bibliography style to surround titles in single quotes in a bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation

I want to make the title show ` ' around it with capitalization being saved. I could go through and manually modify the .bib file I suppose...

Comment: The alternative is to change the style file.  Which style are you using?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120722/how-to-modify-a-bibliography-style-to-surround-titles-in-quotes-in-a-bibliograph help?

Comment: We need some feedback to help: unclear otherwise