# How to modify the abbrvnat bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I want make my bibliography in which there is comma between author and article name instead of full stop. And also i want to write name of article in inverted commas (as x). Is there any way of writing such type of bibliography

**Example:**

```
 G. Agarwal & S. Sindh,"A comparison between public key authority and certification authority for distribution of public key". International Journal of Computer Science and Information Technologies.1(5):332--336,2010.
```

**My bibliography code:**

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
  @article{link:cac,
 title   = {A comparison between public key authority and certification authority for distribution of public key},
 author  = {Agarwal, Gaurav and Singh, Saurabh},
 journal = {International Journal of Computer Science and Information Technologies},
 volume  = {1},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {332--336},
  year    = {2010}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

 \begin{document}
        \noindent
        \citet{link:cac}, \cite{link:cac}
        \bibliography{mybib}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: This should be easy to do with `biblatex`.

Comment: @Bernard    but how?

Comment: Which style would you use? Numeric, authoryear, alphabetoc?  Usually, one starts with a style close to what one wants, and add some  customisation.

Comment: @Bernard The MWE makes it quite clear it's a numbered style, `abbrvnat`. A `biblatex` answer would also be useful to have, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most traditional BiBTeX formatting issues, this requires hacking the `.bst` file itself, but it's not that hard to do. An alternative is to use `biblatex`.

First locate the original `abbrvnat.bst` file.  You can find the exact path for your system by using `kpsewhich abbrvnat.bst` from the command line. On a current TeXLive system it is in:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/natbib/abbrvnat.bst
```

Make a copy of this file, and call it e.g. `abbrvnat-quotes.bst`.  Put this in your local `texmf` folder: `...texmf/bibtex/bst/` or simply place it in the same folder as your source document if you only need this style for that document.

Now you need to make the following changes to the file:

1. Add a new function `enquote` to the file.  This should go with the other functions. A simple way is to find the `emphasize` function and copy it and then make it look like this:

```
FUNCTION {enquote}
 { duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { "``" swap$ * "''" * }
   if$
 }
```

For a more flexible version of the `enquote` function, you can use the `csquotes` package. See [How to modify a bibliography style to surround titles in quotes in a bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120722/2693) for details on how to do this.

2. Find the `article` function (line 699) and make the following modifications:
   Change the following line:

```
format.title "title" output.check
```

to:

```
format.title enquote "title" output.check
```

3. To add a comma after the author name requires more extensive changes, since you need to change the format for every publication type. But the general method is the same.  In each publication type you will find the following lines:

```
author format.key output
new.block
```

You need to change all of these pairs of lines to:

```
author format.key output
```

For more complex items, the simple line `author format.key output` may not be present. In that case you need to look for the `new.block` line that is between the author output code (whatever that is) and the title code. For the `book` type, for example you will find:

```
author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
```

In this case you need to remove the `new.block` line.

Save the file and use `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-quotes}` in your source document.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
  @article{link:cac,
 title   = {A comparison between public key authority and certification authority for distribution of public key},
 author  = {Agarwal, Gaurav and Singh, Saurabh},
 journal = {International Journal of Computer Science and Information Technologies},
 volume  = {1},
  number  = {5},
  pages   = {332--336},
  year    = {2010}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-quotes}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{link:cac}, \cite{link:cac}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @sam Did you delete your `.aux` files and recompile? Did any of the changes have an effect?

Comment: @sam Does the sample document in my answer work? What do the first 4 lines of the `.blg` file say after you run `bibtex`?

Comment: @sam That's not the `.blg` of the sample answer. And that's not the first four lines of the file, which should begin with "This is BibTeX, version ..."  What does the line beginning with "The style file: " show?

Comment: @sam This shows that you are not using the new copy of the `.bst` file that you created. Did you change the `\bibliographystyle` command in your thesis to `abbrvnat-quotes` (which is the filename I suggested for the modified copy?)

Comment: @sam Are you sure you don't have a second `\bibliographystyle` command lurking somewhere later in the document?

Comment: @sam I really don't know what to say.  The file reported in the `.blg` file should match the file in the `bibliographystyle` command assuming you are starting with all the `.aux, .blg, .bbl` files deleted.

Comment: oh sorry, i forget to delete the `.blg` and `.bbl` files. Now it works. But not work in references of `@books` and `@inproceedings` `@misc`.

Comment: @sam Which part doesn't work for these items? The quotation marks or the comma part?

Comment: both are not working. This is only working for article

Comment: @sam First of all, book titles shouldn't be in quotation marks; they should be in italics. Second, did you remove the `new.block` lines from between the author code and the title code for all of the entries?  I've updated the answer to show how to do this for the `book`. type.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the `biblatex` way. Loading `csquotes`, you have a choice for the quotes style. The default is `american` quotes, but you may have `british`, `guillemets`, &c. It cooperates with `babel` or `polyglossia`.

Note the differences with the traditional way: the bibliography style is an option of `biblatex` the .bib files have to be declared in the preamble with the command `\addbibresource{mybib.bib}` (with extension), and the bibliography is called with `\printbibliography` where you want it. The bibliography engine by default is `biber`, but you can use bibtex with the option `backend=bibtex`, at the price of the loss  of some functionalities. In particular, `biber` understands `utf8`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
  @article{link:cac,
 title = {A comparison between public key authority and certification authority for distribution of public key},
 author = {Agarwal, Gaurav and Singh, Saurabh},
 journal = {International Journal of Computer Science and Information Technologies},
 volume = {1},
  number = {5},
  pages = {332--336},
  year = {2010}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
 \usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}%
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\cite{link:cac}, \textcite{link:cac}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I think the requested style needs double quotation marks, not single, though. Also, I would really only advise using `bibtex` as a back end as an absolute last resort.

Comment: It was just for a demo of what can easily be done.