# How to use APA format for references with 'unsrt' bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

I want my references to be cited within text using the square brackets and with the order they appear in the thesis like this `[1]`. While the reference to be in APA like format like this:

> [1] Bouwkamp, J.G., and Bolhom, J.K, 1963, “Dynamic Response of a Two-
>   Story Steel Frame Structure “ , Bulletin of the Seismological Society
>   of America , Vol.56, No. 6, Dec.,1963 , pp. 1289- 1303.

I tried using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt,apalike}` but seems we can't mix both, so how to produce the above format?

Using the `apalike` only produced references that are not ordered by the order of their appearance in text. And using `unsrt` only produced reference format like:

> [1] J.G. Bouwkamp and J.K. Bolhom. Dynamic Response of a Two- Story
>   Steel Frame Structure  , Bulletin of the Seismological Society of
>   America , Vol.56, No. 6, pp. 1289- 1303, 1963.

SO I want to make citation style like "unsrt" but Bibliography style as "APA", how to do this?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. APA defines intext quotes to be author, date.

Comment: apalike produces Author, date, title but without double quotes " around " and the references are not ordered according to the order of citation, do you know a way to edit this apalike style to produce the output stated above in question, I will try someway for making a new bst file like here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120722/how-to-modify-a-bibliography-style-to-surround-titles-in-quotes-in-a-bibliograph) and will let you know if it worked

Comment: APA is a relatively strict author date style (harvard). The bibiography is supposed to be sorted alphabetically, as opposed to numerically and by order of citation as known for the vancouver system. `unsrt` is a style of the vancouver family, APA is style of the harvard family.

Comment: But unfortunately, the required format mixes both :( thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this easily with `natbib` but you can do it quite simply with `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{incollection,
    Author = {AuthorOne, First and AuthorTwo, Second and AuthorThree, Third and AuthorFour, Fourth},
    Booktitle = {Edited Book on Important Stuff},
    Editor = {EditorOne, Ed and EditorTwo, Ed},
    Title = {Article Title},
    Year = {2017}}

@inproceedings{inproceedings,
    Author = {AuthorOne, First and AuthorTwo, Second and AuthorThree, Third and AuthorFour, Fourth},
    Booktitle = {Proceedings of the Conference on Important Stuff},
    Title = {Article Title},
    Year = {2016}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[bibstyle=apa,citestyle=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{[#1]}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list 
    {\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}} 
  {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}% 
   \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}% 
   \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}% 
   \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}% 
   \setlength{\itemindent}{\labelwidth}% 
   \addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelsep}% 
   \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}% 
   \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}} 
{\endlist} 
{\item}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Citing something \autocite{incollection}

Citing something else \autocite{inproceedings}


Citing again \autocite{incollection}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: But this have the same effect as using `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`, but what I want is to have : Citing something \autocite{incollection} =>[1]

Citing something else \autocite{inproceedings}[2]

and  
Citing again \autocite{incollection} [1] with the references having the APA style but the title within quotes " "

Comment: Add `sorting=none` to the `biblatex` options. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I received an error with biblatex not found!!, will check what is the problem and get back to you.