# How to make report title quoted instead of italicized with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

As the title says, I want to have quoted title for reports, just like for articles.

I tried doing this (suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341768/35990)):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[%
  article,inproceedings,misc,online,proceedings,techreport,report
]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
```

which did make titles of `@misc` and `@online` quoted, but didn't change anything for `@report` or `@techreport`.

How can I make this work for reports? Is the title field called something else for reports?

For reference, here's my preamble:

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  useprefix=true,
  backref=true,
  backrefstyle=three,
  style=numeric-comp
]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into trouble with trailing whitespace in the list.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[%
  article,inproceedings,misc,online,proceedings,techreport,report
]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
```

doesn't work because the last list item is `report`  with a space and not `report`.

`biblatex.def` uses the form

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inproceedings,misc,online,proceedings,techreport,report]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
```

which avoids trailing spaces. (Note that after a comma, the space is optional and will be ignored if present. That is not the case at the end of the list, however.)

But these lines can be shortened significantly, since some types mentioned already have `\mkbibquote{#1}` set up and `@techreport` is an alias for `@report` (this alias is set up in a way that means that `biblatex` internally does not know the type `@techreport`)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc,online,proceedings,report]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  useprefix=true,
  backref=true,
  backrefstyle=three,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc,online,proceedings,report]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{chiu,padhye}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: W. W. Chiu and W. M. Chow. ‘A Hybrid Hierarchical Model of a Multiple Virtual Storage (MVS) Operating System’. Research rep. RC-6947. IBM, 1978 (cit. on p. 1).//J. Padhye, V. Firoiu and D. Towsley. ‘A Stochastic Model of TCP Reno Congestion Avoidance and Control’. Tech. rep. 99-02. Amherst, Mass.: University of Massachusetts, 1999 (cit. on p. 1).]