# getting "You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry" error with custom bst file

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I generated a custom bst file using "latex makebst.tex" [2003/09/08 4.1 (PWD, AO)], with no obvious errors, but bibtex gives an "You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry" error for every @BOOK, @INBOOK and @INCOLLECTION entry of my bib file. I've read several remedies for this error message on the web but none seem to apply here. Is there any way I can make the dbj and bst files available to someone who can figure out what I did wrong with makebst, or how to patch the bst file? The 30000 character limit precludes posting them here.

Comment: Please share the relevant `.bst` file on a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/, https://gist.github.com/, https://gitlab.com/explore/snippets, ... Please include a small example document along with a few relevant `.bib` entries in your question so that we can immediately replicate the issue.

Comment: OK, the dbj, bst and an example bib files are now available at "https://gist.github.com/TimFH/546f9805886719ab696cd084211847bf"

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue in `FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}`.

The following version works for me

```
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
      year empty$
        'skip$
        { t empty$ address empty$ and
            'skip$
            { ", " * }
          if$
          year "year" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

The only change is from `{ ", " swap$ * * }` to

```
{ ", " * }
```

In the `<false>` branch of the `t empty$ address empty$ and` conditional.

---

That said, the combination

```
pub-date,pub-xpar
```

among

```
%<<PUBLISHER IN PARENTHESES:
%   %: (def) Publisher as normal block without parentheses
% pub-par,%: Publisher in parentheses 
% pub-date,%: Publisher and date in parentheses (Oxford, 1994)
% pub-date,pub-xc,%: Publisher and date in parentheses, no comma (Oxford 1994)
  pub-date,pub-xpar,%: Publisher and date without parentheses Oxford, 1994
% pub-date,pub-xpar,pub-xc,%: Publisher and date, no parentheses, no comma Oxford 1994
%------\ans=f(==pub-date,pub-xpar)-------
%>>PUBLISHER IN PARENTHESES:
```

looks pretty odd on first glance.

If you select neither option, you get a `.bst` whose `FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}` looks much saner. The only difference between `pub-date,pub-xpar` and not giving the two options is the position of the year with respect to the edition. With the options, the year comes before the `edition`, without the options the `edition` would be wedged in between year and publisher/address.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to have fixed it; thank you! I agree that my choice of options is odd, but the way this journal formats references is also a bit odd. I still have to figure out a way to quote the book titles, for example (or add them by hand). The following post seems to show how: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120722/how-to-modify-a-bibliography-style-to-surround-titles-in-quotes-in-a-bibliograph