# Add quotes around some reference titles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, bibliographystyle

In the following book sample, I'm using the `natbib` package to generate the bibliography with a specific style as described in [this page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles). However, some reference titles—such as of articles (and other reference types)—are generated without quotes. Therefore, I was wondering how to add quotes around these reference titles—excluding that of books (which should remain italicized without quotes).

I checked the solution of @AlanMunn [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120722/how-to-modify-a-bibliography-style-to-surround-titles-in-quotes-in-a-bibliograph), but I would rather—as a Windows user—not to manipulate any external file. Besides, the `biblatex` solution of @JoeCorneli (2nd answer) did not work in the sense that it did not generate any bibliography section at all.

Thanks for any suggestion you could provide.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extbook}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{natbib}

\title{Book Title}

\author{Author}
\date{}

\newcommand\institute{
    Department \par \medskip
    University \par
    City, State}


\begin{document}
    
    \frontmatter
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \makeatletter
        \centering
        {\LARGE\bfseries\baselineskip1.25em\@title\par} \par
        \vfill
        {\large\bfseries\@author} \par
        \@date
        \makeatother
        \vfill
        \pgfornament[width=.35\linewidth]{84} \bigskip \par
        \institute
    \end{titlepage}
    
    % Empty page
    \phantom{}
    \pagebreak
    
    % Dedication
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begingroup
    \centering
    \lipsum[1-1]
    \endgroup
    \vspace*{\fill}
    
    \chapter{Preface}  
    \lipsum[2-3]
    
    \tableofcontents
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \lipsum[4-6]
    
    \mainmatter
    
    \chapter{Title 1}
    \lipsum[5-9]
    \citep{Karmarkar:84}
    
    \chapter{Title 2}
    \lipsum[10-14]
    
    \backmatter     
    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}        
    \bibliography{references.bib}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT (1)**

In light of @AlanMunn comments below, the `biblatex` solution needs to be compiled with `biber`, which explains why it did not work for me in the first place. However, the generated reference style is not similar to the desired `abbrvnat` style [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles); please see the figure below.

[image]

---

**EDIT (2)**

In light of @cfr comments below, I'm adding the contents of a separate `bibtex` file—`reference.bib`—that includes the reference entries.

```
@article{Karmarkar:84,
    author = {Karmarkar, Narendra},
    title = {{A New Polynomial-Time Algorithm for Linear Programming}},
    journal = {Combinatorica},
    year = {1984},
    volume = {4},
    number = {4},
    pages = {373-395}
}
```

Comment: If you are sticking to `natbib` then you are forced to use the kind of solution given in my answer. But it's not "changing a system file", but modifying a copy of a system file. Not the same thing. Furthermore that solution provides you a way to create your own `.bst` file from scratch using `makebst`.  If you're able to use `biblatex` then the other solution should work, in which case you need to explain what you mean by "[it] didn't work".

Comment: @AlanMunn: I'm not using italics and quotation marks at the same time. Book titles should be italicized without quotes, while titles of other reference types should have quotes but not italicized. Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your question. I'll delete the second comment. :)

Comment: It's fine. I will add the error message for the `biblatex` solution.

Comment: Remember that if you change to the `biblatex` solution you should delete all your `.aux` files, and you need to compile the bibliography with `biber` not `bibtex`.  If you're using Overleaf, the compilation should be automatic, but if you're using a local distribution you may need to configure your editor to use `biber`.

Comment: OK, thank you; that explains why it didn't work in the first place. However, the style is different from `natbib`'s `abbrvnat` (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles) which is the one that I need to use.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a solution using `natbib` other that editing the `.bst`, since I'm a Windows user with a local distribution.

Comment: Well that solution uses `apa` but if you load `biblatex` without any style, you'll get something very close to `abbrvnat`.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Please see the figure in the new edit.

Comment: Your example appears to hardcode the bibliography i.e. not to use BibTeX or Biber/Biblatex etc. at all?

Comment: @cfr: I need `natbib` style with quotes for titles other than book references.

Comment: In your example, you hardcode the reference information, you you can just use quotes in place of `\emph{}`. I assume your real document doesn't hardcode them and you need a different example to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Some of the changes you want to apply to the `biblatex` style are FAQs and straightforward. They can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864 (don't always take the very first answer you come across, shop around and compare). ...

Comment: ... If you remove the number presumably you want to cite entries with author-year style in your document. In that case pass `style=authoryear,` to `biblatex` as an option. Then the year will be moved to right after the authors and not to the end. That makes sense, because a work is identified by author and year. Having the year at the end of the entry makes it less prominent and thus harder to find.

Comment: Do note though: If you *have to* use `abbrvnat` switching to `biblatex` is not a good idea. `biblatex` uses its own style format and cannot use `natbib`'s/BibTeX's styles. While there are generally `biblatex` styles that look broadly similar to `natbib`/BibTeX styles, it is extremely painful to modify these styles so that they look exactly the same. `biblatex` is most efficient if you want to have easy customisation for common things like titles in quotation marks vs italics vs no markup and can live with the other decisions of the style.

Comment: @cfr: I'm not hardcoding the bibliography. What's inside `\begin{thebibliography} ... \end{thebibliography}` comes from a `.bib` file. I should have mentioned that. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks.