# Replace `et al.` in a citation with all authors surnames of the reference

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, bibliographystyle

In the book MWE used [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691135/add-quotes-around-some-reference-titles), I'm using the `natbib` package to generate the bibliography with the `abbrvnat` style described [in this page](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles). I would like to have the citation of a reference with three authors to include all of their surnames, instead of the first author's surname followed by `et al.`.

The command `\citet*{Byrd:19}` does include all three authors of the particular reference `Byrd:19`, but I need to have everything inside the brackets. Please see the figure below.

The example reference entries, included in a separate `bibtex` file—reference.bib, are:

```
@article{Byrd:19,
    author = {Byrd, Richard~H. and Cocola, Jorio and Tapia, Richard~A.},
    title = {{Extending the Pennisi--McCormick Second-Order Sufficiency Theory for Nonlinear Programming to Infinite Dimensions}},
    journal = {SIAM Journal on Optimization},
    year = {2019},
    volume = {29},
    number = {3},
    pages = {1870-1878}}
```

Thanks for any idea you could provide.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're still using the `abbrvnat` bibliography style, I suggest you (a) load the [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package with the options `square` and `authoryear` and (b) use `\citep*` instead of `\citet*` to create "parenthetic-style" citation call-outs that show *all* authors' surnames. Conversely, use `\citep` to create parenthetic-style citation call-outs with truncated author lists for entries with three or more authors or editors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extreport}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{Byrd:19,
    author = {Byrd, Richard H. and Cocola, Jorio and Tapia, Richard A.},
    title  = {Extending the {Pennisi--McCormick} Second-Order Sufficiency 
             Theory for Nonlinear Programming to Infinite Dimensions},
    journal= {SIAM Journal on Optimization},
    year   = {2019},
    volume = {29},
    number = {3},
    pages  = {1870-1878},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[square,authoryear]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % or some other suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\citep*{Byrd:19}, \citep{Byrd:19}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mico; that does it.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using the `abbrvnat` style as described in my previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691135/add-quotes-around-some-reference-titles). I have edited the current question to reinforce that.