# Trying to get APA work gives Undefined control sequence

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm trying to get APA working with special characters. I got kind of far with it but it gives me Undefined control sequence on rendering citations.

My minimal source is:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[czech,british]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,date=short,maxcitenames=2,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}


\begin{document}
  \cite{test}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My `sample.bib` now looks like. It's encoded with UTF8 for sure

```
@book{test,
    Author = {šýř čžá and íéě č},
    Title = {šýř},
}
```

The error is `Undefined control sequence \datecircaprint \mkbibdateapalongextra`. The encoding is not the issue here I believe.

Comment: I'll try to edit the post with simplified version to better isolate the issue. @moewe I have exactly the same versions

Comment: I've tided the comments: the new issue is rather different from the original one. The edited issue is I think an out-and-out bug in `apa.bbx`. I'll ask the author to take a look!

Comment: You're right, there's some thing else :/ Shoudl I edit this when I isolate it better or delete and create new one?

Comment: I think we are OK here 'zooming in' on the issue: the one 'answer of sorts' to-date may stay or go, depending on what it's author thinks.

Comment: If Czech is the main language you need something like `\DeclareLanguageMapping{czech}{czech-apa}`, but there is no such thing as `czech-apa.lbx`. So you can't really use `biblatex-apa` in Czech right now without providing your own `.lbx` file. I'll check if there is a duplicate or write an answer later.

Comment: A good start is [Using biblatex-apa](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80440/35864)

Comment: Thank you for that. Have you tried it? It doesn't work for me. I have created and edited that file in the correct location but it still can't find czech-apa.lbx. Anyway, it's not the problem I have, the problem now is that Undefined control sequence. Or does it compile well for you?

Comment: No, no, no. You have to create your own `czech-apa.lbx`. Just take `english-apa.lbx` as basis and translate the stuff. The `.lbx` file contains the definition of the missing control sequence `\mkbibdateapalongextra` (amongst others).

Comment: I did that exactly :) http://pastebin.com/1aEKbijU Created czech-apa.lbx from french-apa.lbx

Comment: And you also added `\DeclareLanguageMapping{czech}{czech-apa}`? You need to move the `.lbx` file to a place where TeX can find it. Check the `.log` file if the `.lbx` is found.

Comment: I wrote in the comment above that in the log it says it can't find czech-apa. Which is very weird because if I change it for example to french-apa, it works. And they are in the same folder lol. http://i.imgur.com/TfPnebp.png

Comment: Aha. If you put it into the directory of your TeX system you need to tell TeX about it. On Tex live run `texhash` (maybe as `su`?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21726/35864. With MikTeX you need to refresh the FNDB. The file will always be found if it is in the current working directory.

Comment: That helped! Even with the another error I asked in a question, it disappeared. Thanks man

Comment: I have decided to close your answer as a duplicate since your edited question is quite evidently about that issue and was solved with the answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writing of `fddd.bib` by LaTeX's environment `filecontents` gets broken after `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Workarounds:

- Move it before:

  ```
  \begin{filecontents}{fddd.bib}
  @book{test,
      Author = {ě+íéíáý řščžčřý},
      Title = {ščřž},
  }
  \end{filecontents}

  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  ```
- Or use package `filecontents`, but caution, it always overwrites the files to be generated:

  ```
  \usepackage{filecontents}% or \RequirePackage{filecontents} before `\documentclass`
  \begin{filecontents}{fddd.bib}
  @book{test,
      Author = {ě+íéíáý řščžčřý},
      Title = {ščřž},
  }
  \end{filecontents}
  ```

LaTeX's `filecontents` only uses verbatim mode via `\dospecials`. Special characters like backslash, hash, ... are written verbatim, but the 8-bit characters are not touched. In the example of the question, they are active by `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and after `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, they are written as characters with encoding `T1`.

Package `filecontents`, however, also sanitizes the 8-bit characters. Thus the entries in UTF-8 are not changed, when written to the `.bib` file.

One issue remains that I get an undefined error because of `\mkbibdateapalongextra`, but I have not checked, that I am using the latest versions.

Comment: Normally Biber is absolutely fine with comments at the beginning of `.bib` files. In the MWE it is rather the problem that the UTF-8 bit is not written raw to the file (as can be seen when opening the `.bib` file). If I load the `filecontents` package, everything is fine even though we still get a comment in the `.bib` file - alternative stuff also works if the `filecontents` environment is moved to the top of the file. It could be that that is not the heart of the issue - I presume the OP initially noticed the issue in a 'productive' environment where I wouldn't assume use of `filecontents`.

Comment: @moewe I got it fixed in a test file right before Windows 10 decides it likes a black screen much more :-((((. Of course, the test file was gone and I had assumed the wrong reason. The real was not the star form, see updated answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, the issue persisted. I have simplified and edited my question, now I have the same error with `\ mkbibdateapalongextra`. I believe the wrongly encoded characters warning comes after this one

Comment: @simPod There are two issues. The encoding issue is answered. The undefined control sequence is open, as I have written in the last sentence. It seems to be fixed in newer versions.