# Question Related to use of citation management packages

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, apacite

I try to use bib file to do my reference in latex, it was fine for a test document I did, the test document is shown as following

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\title{Investigations of parametric similar waves}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

Blah blah blah blah \citet{Turner2009}

\bibliography{MyCollection}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}


\end{document}
```

However, when I tried to implement it in another report, it does not work. The following are all the packages I used in my report. I suspect the problem is caused by one of package i used to do plots, but i am not sure how to fix it, anyone has any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[margin=0.85in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in ]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newsavebox{\largestimage}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlength{\mylen}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}

\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\tablename\enspace}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\mylen}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[backref=true,backend=biber,natbib=true,hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{refs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     citecolor    = gray
}
\begin{document}

\title{Investigations of parametric similar waves}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

Blah blah blah blah \citet{Turner2009}




 \bibliography{MyCollection.bib}
 \bibliographystyle{apacite}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: The second file also loads `biblatex`, which is fundamentally incompatible with `natbib`. You must choose to use one or the other.

Comment: Please do not quote code. It should be formatted as code. Highlight it and click `{}` or use ctrl+k. If you have problems, leave it unformatted. It is easier to correct than it is if you quote it. (Much easier.)

Comment: @jon thanks for the reply, but say if i want to use biblatex, how should i do the reference..

Comment: thanks for the reply, I just tried to unquote all the codes..new to the site, i was a bit confused. I will have a look, c what i can do.

Comment: As for `biblatex` in the APA style, see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80491/8528) (note that the answer is also trying to use the 'canadian' variant of English, which you can probably skip). If you use `biblatex`, you cannot load any of these: `apacite` or `natbib`; and you cannot use the `\bibliographystyle`. Please try the answer I suggested, however, and see if that helps.

Comment: See [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693) for an explanation of the differences.  For `apa` citations see [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793/2693) and the question @jon linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments about the first document: You may claim that "it was fine for a test document I did". However, this can't be the case except maybe for an extremely limited test document. Specifically, you should never load both the `apacite` package and the `natbib` package. In fact, since you're specifying `apacite` as the bibliography style, you should *definitely not* load the `natbib` package. If you prefer using natbib's citation commands `\citet` and `\citep`, you should load the `apacite` package as follows:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

---

The second document suffers from an even bigger problem: Not only do you again load both `apacite` and `natbib`, you then load `biblatex` as well. The three packages are mutually incompatible. Another major problem is that the document features not one but two [!] `\bibliography` statements. No wonder things went haywire. Your conjecture, "I suspect the problem is caused by one of package i used to do plots", does not appear to be supported by the facts on the ground.

If you've had otherwise good experiences with the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style, you should definitely *not* be loading either the `biblatex` or the `natbib` package.

Your second document suffers from some additional problems. For instance, I can think of no valid reason whatsoever for loading the `latexsym` package in a LaTeX2e document, the more so since you're also loading the `amssymb` package. There can also be no justification for loading the `color` package if you're going to override all of its capabilities by subsequently loading the `xcolor` package.